# How to pass the parameter to autonomous function and get the values?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

On load of the document, I am initiating a function calling itself. And later from the returned function, i am trying to get the output. but i am not getting. the way what i do this wrong here.

any one correct me and teach the correct way to use the self initiated functions?

here is my try :

```
var BankAccount = (function () { 

  function BankAccount() { 
    this.balance = 0; 
  } 

  BankAccount.prototype.deposit = function(credit) { 
    this.balance += credit; return this.balance; 
  }; 

  return BankAccount; 

})();

var myDeposit = BankAccount.deposit(50); //throws error as ankAccount.deposit is not a function
```

[Live](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNdoKO?editors=0012)

Comment: `new BankAccount().deposit(50);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return instance of BankAccount:

```
return new BankAccount();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke your constructor before you can call `.deposit`

```
var account = new BankAccount();
var balance = account.deposit(50);
console.log(balance); // 50
```

This would allow you to manage multiple accounts where each account has its own balance.

```
var a = new BankAccount();
a.deposit(50); // 50

var b = new BankAccount();
b.deposit(20); // 20

console.log(a.balance); // 50
console.log(b.balance); // 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You've written a constructor function, but you haven't called it as one.

```
var myBankAccount = new BankAccount();
var myDeposit = myBankAccount.deposit(50);
```